# Unable to post datetime type python

Tags: python, datetime, post, python-requests

I am trying to post an object containing DateTime type using python requests library. The object looks like

```py
data_json = {
    'title': str(row[5]),
    'Type': 'type',
    'subtype': 'subtype',
    'uuid': str(uuid.uuid4()),
    'created_at': timestamp,
    'updated_at': timestamp,
    'code': str(row[8]),
    'version': 1,
}
```

The timestamp=`datetime.datetime.now()` and `data=json.dumps(data_json)`
The post call was like

> response=requests.post(API_ENDPOINT,headers=header,data=data)

This did not work. If I converted timestamp to string using `str` or `strftime`, I get an error saying `created_at must be datetime type`. Similarly with updated_at.
Desperate to get it working I also used [this](https://blag.nullteilerfrei.de/2017/10/29/python-post-json-data-containing-a-datetime-object-with-requests-to-flask/) solution but to no avail.

Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: which API are you trying to post to? You would have to serialize the datetime object before it can be sent over http.

The format will be determined by what the api on the other end is expecting to find.

Comment: The API is the endpoint given by python eve framework. How do I serialize it? In the backend it's uses datetime.datetime.utcnow(). I tried using it. That way also didn't work.

Comment: its not requests but python-eve's configuration at the core of your problem.
please share the configuration file for eve.

Comment: @AnuvratParashar this is exactly my final thought. However, I don't have access to the python-eve backend. But I thought that the post should work if I'm doing exactly as the backend python-eve. It doesn't work even then.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation at https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/config.html?highlight=date_format

> A Python date format used to parse and render datetime values. When serving requests, matching JSON strings will be parsed and stored as datetime values. In responses, datetime values will be rendered as JSON strings using this format. Defaults to the RFC1123 (ex RFC 822) standard a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT (“Tue, 02 Apr 2013 10:29:13 GMT”).

Eve expects the format you specify in the configuration.
You could get the datetime in default format using something like this(python>3.3):

```
from email.utils import format_datetime
from datetime import datetime
format_datetime(datetime.now())
```

For older python, following snippet should work

```
from email.utils import formatdate
utils.formatdate(datetime.now().toordinal())
```

Or otherwise, if you have set the `DATE_FORMAT` configuration parameter, you can use the same formatting string with `strptime`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using format_datetime is not working. I didn't use DATE_FORMAT.

Comment: I am using python 3.6.

Comment: that s interesting.

Comment: using utils.formatdate(datetime.now().toordinal()) I get "created_at": "must be of datetime type" error.